# for cookie poisoning demo, write and read cookies in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, cookies

I would like to test cookie poisoning so I want to edit one of my projects. There, I would like to write cookies which will contain subtotal of products and the checkout page will use it again to show the subtotal. I am not sure whether my thinking is correct or not and also my cookies are not working.

First, I put these codes under addcart button method:

```
Dim aCookie As New HttpCookie("SubTotal")
aCookie.Value = objShopCart.ComputeSubTotal().ToString()
aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie)
```

And in the checkout page;

```
If (Request.Cookies("aCookie") IsNot Nothing) Then
    Dim subTotal As String
    If (Request.Cookies("aCookie")("SubTotal") IsNot Nothing) Then
        subTotal = Request.Cookies("aCookie")("SubTotal")
        lblSubTotal.Text = subTotal
    End If
End If
```

According to the above codes, I cannot read the cookies. The `Request.Cookies("aCookie")` is always nothing I don't know why. And for the cookie poisoning demo is I intend to intercept the cookie of when I put things into the shopcart and edit it so when I got to checkout page, its shown with wrong info of subtotal etc. Appreciate to any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to retrieve the cookie value by the same name you saved it. For example,

```
If (Request.Cookies("SubTotal") IsNot Nothing) Then
   Dim subTotal As String
   subTotal = Request.Cookies("SubTotal").Value
End If
```

*Just FYI, you do not want to save the subtotal in cookie, because it can be manipulated easily at client side. Save it in session state or recalculate it in check out page again.*

Comment: I need to do a demo under a security topic. That's why I just want to save in cookie. Before that, I save the subtotal in session state.

Comment: I see. Does this Request.Cookies("SubTotal").Value solve your problem?

Comment: yes it does solve the problem and thank you. I'll ask again if i got further small issues.

Comment: I know cookies can be manipulated easily at client side. But I don't know how to. Do you have any idea?